# UPS shipping method not working on drupal 7?

Tags: ubercart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubercart UPS Shipping Method not working?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53623/ubercart-ups-shipping-method-not-working)

I am having an issue with setting up Ubercart with my UPS account to allow the customer to configure shipping quotes. After I fill in all of the address information and I click on the "Click to calculate shipping" button, I keep getting the same error message:

> There were problems getting a shipping quote. Please verify the delivery and product information and try again. If this does not resolve the issue, please call in to complete your order.

I have no idea what the issue could be. I'm not sure if there is a setting or configuration that I missed or if it's something else. I'm not sure what information any of you would need to determine the issue, so if someone thinks that they could help me, let me know what information might be needed and I can get it.