# Ubercart UPS Shipping Method not working?

Tags: ubercart

I completed the configuration option on UPs Shipping quote page, after that i will go to the checkout page means it will show the  following error:

> Hard 110002: No packages in shipment
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
>   <AccessLicenseNumber>3CAA21FCE19Ass83BA</AccessLicenseNumber>
>   <UserId>thewdddallsticker</UserId>
>   <Password>wallsticfdgkeR1</Password>
> </AccessRequest>
>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang="en-US">
>   <Request>
>     <TransactionReference>
>       <CustomerContext>Complex Rate Request</CustomerContext>
>       <XpciVersion>1.0001</XpciVersion>
>     </TransactionReference>
> ```

Comment: Don't know about Ubercart, but if you create a shipment with 0 packages with UPS it will not get processed as the message states. Try to see the xml (or whatever file) being generated by the module and search for `<NumberOfPackages>` under `<ShipmentInformation>`.